# Shortcut for clearing Firebug's console

Tags: console, firebug

I have RFTM'ed Firebug's documentation and made this question longer so that SO will allow me to submit it.

Is there a keyboard command to clear the console in Firebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in 2.0 alphas. You can see it by opening the ["Customize Shortcuts" dialog](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Shortcut_Bindings).

You can get that info from the [shortcuts page](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts) on the Firebug wiki.